# Greengrass V2 continuously giving me MqttProxyIPCAgent Not Authorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

I have the following Greengrass V2 custom recipe:

```
---
RecipeFormatVersion: "2020-01-25"
ComponentName: com.savic.Telemetry
ComponentVersion: 1.0.12
ComponentDescription: Vehicle telemetry consisting of CAN and additional messages
ComponentPublisher: ##############
ComponentConfiguration:
  DefaultConfiguration:
    Environment: nonprod
    accessControl:
      aws.greengrass.ipc.mqttproxy:
        com.savic.Telemetry:pubsub:2:
          policyDescription: Allows access to publish to telemetry topic
          operations:
            - aws.greengrass#PublishToIoTCore
          resources:
            - savicmc/{configuration:/Environment}/telemetry/events
Manifests:
  - Platform:
      os: linux
    Lifecycle:
      Setenv:
        SAVICMC_ENV: "{configuration:/Environment}"
        SAVIC_SENDLOG_PATH: "/var/log/sendLog.txt"
        SAVIC_SAMPLE_RATE: 10
        SAVIC_TELEMETRY_TOPIC: "savicmc/{configuration:/Environment}/telemetry/events"
      Install:
        RequiresPrivilege: true
        script: python3 -m pip install --user awsiotsdk
      Run:
        RequiresPrivilege: true
        script: python3 -u {artifacts:path}/telemetry.py
    Artifacts:
      - Uri: s3://greengrass-components-#############-############/artifacts/com.savic.Telemetry/1.0.12/telemetry.py
        Permission:
          Execute: OWNER
```

NOTE: I also tried a variation of the accessControl:

```
  aws.greengrass.ipc.mqttproxy:
    com.savic.Telemetry:mqttproxy:2:

 ------ AND --------

  aws.greengrass.ipc.mqttproxy:
    com.savic.Telemetry:pubsub:2:
```

(note: pubsub vs. mqttproxy)

However, in my greengrass.log, I am continuously getting the following:

```
2022-01-24T06:29:45.178Z [INFO] (Thread-8) software.amazon.awssdk.eventstreamrpc.RpcServer: New connection code [AWS_ERROR_SUCCESS] for [Id 1141, Class ServerConnection, Refs 1](2022-01-24T06:29:45.178120Z) - <null>. {}
2022-01-24T06:29:45.181Z [INFO] (Thread-8) software.amazon.awssdk.eventstreamrpc.ServiceOperationMappingContinuationHandler: aws.greengrass#GreengrassCoreIPC authenticated identity: com.savic.Telemetry. {}
2022-01-24T06:29:45.184Z [INFO] (Thread-8) software.amazon.awssdk.eventstreamrpc.ServiceOperationMappingContinuationHandler: Connection accepted for com.savic.Telemetry. {}
2022-01-24T06:29:45.185Z [INFO] (Thread-8) software.amazon.awssdk.eventstreamrpc.ServiceOperationMappingContinuationHandler: Sending connect response for com.savic.Telemetry. {}
2022-01-24T06:29:45.191Z [INFO] (Thread-8) com.aws.greengrass.builtin.services.mqttproxy.MqttProxyIPCAgent: Not Authorized. {error=Principal com.savic.Telemetry is not authorized to perform aws.greengrass.ipc.mqttproxy:aws.greengrass#PublishToIoTCore on resource savicmc/nonprod/telemetry/events}
```

Note the:

```
com.aws.greengrass.builtin.services.mqttproxy.MqttProxyIPCAgent: Not Authorized. {error=Principal com.savic.Telemetry is not authorized to perform aws.greengrass.ipc.mqttproxy:aws.greengrass#PublishToIoTCore on resource savicmc/nonprod/telemetry/events}
```

My Thing device certificate also has a policy that allows `iot:*` and `greengrass:*` so from Policy/IAM perspective, I am allowed to publish.

Any ideas why I am getting the Not Authorized on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Recipes variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/component-recipe-reference.html#recipe-variables) are supported in only the lifecycle section of the recipe. As a result, the `{configuration:/Environment}` string in `accessControl` doesn't resolve to the value that you expect.

```
savicmc/{configuration:/Environment}/telemetry/events
```

You can change the default `accessControl` to use the value of `Environment` by default, so the component works as expected when you use the default values.

```
ComponentConfiguration:
  DefaultConfiguration:
    Environment: nonprod
    accessControl:
      aws.greengrass.ipc.mqttproxy:
        com.savic.Telemetry:pubsub:2:
          policyDescription: Allows access to publish to telemetry topic
          operations:
            - aws.greengrass#PublishToIoTCore
          resources:
            - savicmc/nonprod/telemetry/events
```

When you [configure and deploy the component](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/create-deployments.html) with a different value for `Environment`, you can also update the topic in `accessControl`. For example, you can specify the following [configuration merge update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/update-component-configurations.html) to change `Environment` and the resource topic to `prod`.

```
{
  "Environment": "prod"
  "accessControl": {
    "aws.greengrass.ipc.mqttproxy": {
      "com.savic.Telemetry:pubsub:2": {
        "resources": {
          "savicmc/prod/telemetry/events
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I actually ended up figuring out both of your answers, shortly after I posted the question. First, I thought it was the recipe variables not evaluating inside accessControl - which didn't work for me, and then as you've pointed out, it was the merge that kept on stuffing me around as well. I have accepted this answer on both counts. Thank you.